# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '11\xa0693,70'

Tags: python, pandas

Необходимо найти сумму столбца sum в диапазоне строк 259-368.Для этого нужно перевести тип столбца в int или float. Но выдает ошибку ValueError: could not convert string to float: '11\xa0693,70'   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Gvg1WdBLdaXmLraoslhHn1PG1P4jqiYH

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
#print(test.index)
#print(test.columns)
df['sum'] = df['sum'].astype(float).fillna(0)
general_sum = df.loc[259:368, 'sum'].sum()
print(sum1)
```

Comment: вы предлагаете нам воспользоваться телепатией, чтобы узнать, что у вас там в data.csv?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Извините. Добавил ссылку

Comment: по вашей ссылке нет доступа к файлу. в любом случае, принципиальный ответ я вам дал.

Comment: Изменил статус доступа. Теперь открыт.

Comment: Забейте ржавый гвоздь в голову тому, кто готовил Вам данные.

Comment: Странно - в примере data.csv, по ссылке - data.xlsx

Comment: Потому что я с телефона ссылку добавил. Нет выбора при этом какой файл. Но когда загружаешь файл на ПК так есть выбор в каком формате загрузить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> выдает ошибку ValueError: could not convert string to float: `11\xa0693,70`

Символ `\xa0` - это nbsp, неразрывный пробел.
Он используется в числах вместо обычного пробела (разделителя тысяч), чтобы в тексте число `11 693,70` не разбилось переносом строки на два числа `11` и `693,70`.
А библиотечные функции обычно знают только про обычный пробел и не знают про его многочисленные разновидности за пределами ASCII7.

Как пофиксить: перед конвертацией строки в число нужно преобразовывать строку (т.е., весь csv-файл), заменяя все возможные пробелы на обычные пробелы.  На практике при работе с русскими текстами мне всегда хватало преобразования одного только nbsp.

Comment: Спасибо. Большое за помощь и разъяснения. А вот этот метод pd.to_numeric не будет работать для достижения нужного результата? И есть ли какой то универсальный способ заменить все возможные пробелы или это и есть универсальный?

Answer (score 0):

В подобных вопросах нужно приводить пример исходных данных, чтобы проблему можно было воспроизвести. В общем же случае, воспользуйтесь методом `pd.to_numeric` с указанием обработки ошибок. Например:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"sum":[1,13,"abv", None, True]})
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

```
    sum
0     1
1    13
2   abv
3  None
4  True
sum    object  <--- строки
dtype: object
```

```
df["sum"] = pd.to_numeric(df["sum"], errors="coerce").fillna(0)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

```
    sum
0   1.0
1  13.0
2   0.0
3   0.0
4   1.0
sum    float64 <--- числа
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к совершенно правильному ответу @ESkri внесу техническую часть.
Удаление `\xa0` - ключевой момент, но нужно сначала привести все значения в столбце к типу str перед заменой символов, а перед преобразованием во float еще заменить запятые на точки.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\test\data.csv')
df['sum'] = df['sum'].fillna(0).astype(str).str.replace('\xa0', '').str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
general_sum = df.loc[259:368, 'sum'].sum()
print(general_sum)
```

```
861874.1699999997
```